# Probability about hitting time of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

The question is as following:

Denote $T_a = inf\{t\geq 0|B_t =a\}$, how to compute $P(T_1<T_{-1}<T_2)$?

Comment: My idea is that we have $P = P(T_1<T_{-1}<T_2|T_1<T_{-1})P(T_1<T_{-1})+P(T_1<T_{-1}<T_2|T_1\geq T_{-1})P(T_1\geq T_{-1})$ by law of total probability, then we have $P=\frac{1}{2}P(T_{-1}<T_2)$. So this question is reduced by computing $P(T_{-1}<T_2)$

Comment: $P(T_1<T_{-1})=\frac{1}{2}$ by symmetry

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

For this to happen, the first exit from $(-1,1)$ started at $0$ must be through $1$. Compute the probability of this happening.

Next, compute the probability that the first exit from $(-1,2)$ of a BM started at $1$ is through $-1$. (I will point out for you that the result here is *not* the same as the result for the first part.)

Now use the strong Markov property to infer that the desired probability is the product of these two.

Comment: I add my idea in the comment, the problem is how to compute $P(T_{-1}<T_2)$?

Comment: @calibertytz The problem in the second part is *not* to compute $P(T_{-1}<T_2)$. In order to use a conditioning argument you need to take into account where you are restarting the process, as I mentioned in my answer: you are ultimately computing $P(T_{-1}<T_2)$ for a BM started at $1$, not a BM started at $0$. Since BM is translation invariant this is the same as $P(T_{-2}<T_1)$ for a BM started at 0. That said, your class or textbook has probably discussed methods for computing the exit distribution of BM.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have figure out how to compute $P(T_{-1}<T_2)$.

Let $T=min(T_{-1},T_2)$, which is a new bounded stopping time. By bounded stopping time theorem, we have $E(B_{T})=E(B_0)=-1P(T_{-1}<T_2)+2P(T_{-1}>T_2)=2-3P(T_{-1}<T_2)$, then 
$P(T_{-1}<T_2)=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: If you mean when starting from 0, this is not right. When starting from 0, $E(B_T)=0=-3P(T_{-1}<T_2)+2$. This should be intuitive, when starting at zero it should be more likely to go out of $-1$ because it is closer. But you do not want to start from 0 in this problem, because you needed to get to 1 first and then restart.

Comment: Sorry , I made a calculation mistake, the probability is $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: The probability you wrote is 2/3, but again you need to start everything at 1 instead of 0 which changes things.